# Meteor: How do you use Accounts.findUserByUsername()?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm looking at this as the preferred way to find users by case-insensitive username search [Accounts.findUserByUsername()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Accounts-findUserByUsername)

But according to the docs, it's a server method, and I cannot find an example of how to call this method.  I tried:

```
user = Meteor.call('Accounts.findUserByUsername', 'myUserName')
```

and I got:

```
Error invoking Method 'Accounts.findUserByUsername': Method 'Accounts.findUserByUsername' not found [404]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a server side method and then call it from the client.  So the server side method will look something like

```
Meteor.methods({
  find_by_username: function(name){
    var user = Accounts.findUserByUsername(name));
    return user;
  }
});
```

Then on the client side you will have to invoke the method with a call, and a callback to handle the response from the server

```
Meteor.call('find_by_username', 'username', find_by_username_callback)

function find_by_username_callback(error,user){
 console.log(user);
}
```